# Wrong result with Sass/Scss formula

Tags: variables, sass, operators

I have a problem with a sass formula, the formula passes, but does not give the right result.

```
@for $i from 0 through 99 {
   $j:0;
   @if $i>15 {
     $j:1; 
   }
   @if $i>31 {
     $j:2; 
   }
   @if $i>47 {
     $j:3; 
   }
   @if $i>63 {
     $j:4; 
   }
   @if $i>79 {
     $j:5; 
   }

   $k:$i%16;

   $calc-pos-y:calc(#{$j*20%} + #{#{$i%8*$i%8}px});
}
```

For example, when `$i=91`, normally `$i%8*$i%8` should be `3*3=9`, so `$calc-pos-x: calc(100% +9px)`. But yet, I get `calc(100% +1px)`.

As I increment `$i`, I successively obtain:

```
  calc(100% +0px)
  calc(100% +1px)
  calc(100% +4px)
  calc(100% +1px)
```

For `$i=88` I get `calc(100% +0px)`, it's good.
For `$i=89` I get `calc(100% +1px)`, it's good.
For `$i=90` I get `calc(100% +4px)`, it's good.

I think for `$i=91` the result is `(91*91)%8`, so `8281%8=1`.

How can i have `3*3=9`?

```
$calc-pos-y:calc(#{$j*20%} + #{#{$i%8}*#{$i%8} px}); //give an error
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple operator precedence problem, you forgot parenthesis in your formula. Try this:

```
$calc-pos-y: calc(#{$j * 20%} + #{($i % 8) * ($i % 8)}px);
```